# Pascal's Triangle in Python (power of 11)

Tags: python

I wanted to write a Python program that prints out the Pascal Triangle for the inputted number of rows.
My code is as follows:

```
inc = int(input('Input number of rows: '))
n = 0
row = []
while n <= inc:
    m = 11 ** n
    row.append(m)
    n += 1
for i in range(0, len(row)):
    row[i] = str(row[i])

result = '\n'.join(row)
print(result)
```

My Output is:

```
1
11
121
```

I wanted to separate each symbol in each line so it would look like a Pascal's triangle. How do I implement that?

Comment: Okay, this method works only for n <= 4. Thank you all for your answers, they helped me out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pretty close, you can just [`str.center`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) each line:

```
inc = int(input('Input number of rows: '))
n = 0
row = []
while n < inc:
    m = 11 ** n
    row.append(m)
    n += 1
for i in range(0, len(row)):
    row[i] = ' '.join(list(str(row[i])))
for i in range(0, len(row)):
    row[i] = row[i].center(len(row[-1]),' ')
result = '\n'.join(row)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
Input number of rows: 4
   1   
  1 1  
 1 2 1 
1 3 3 1
```

A shorter version would be:

```
inc = int(input('Input number of rows: '))
max_len = 2 * len(str(11**inc)) - 1
row = (' '.join([*str(11**p)]).center(max_len,' ') for p in range(inc))
print(*row, sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
Input number of rows: 4
   1   
  1 1  
 1 2 1 
1 3 3 1
```

Comment: why do you print 4 rows, when input is 3 ??

Comment: I just tried to follow OP's algo, `while n <= inc:`, but you are right, I should change it.

Answer (score 1):

You can indent each line by `len(row) - i` and then space each character so that each line is twice as long to balance out the otherwise right alignment.

```
inc = int(input('Input number of rows: '))
n = 0
row = []
while n <= inc:
    m = 11 ** n
    row.append(m)
    n += 1
for i in range(0, len(row)):
    indent = " " * (len(row) - i)
    spaced_row = " ".join(list(str(row[i])))
    row[i] = indent + spaced_row

result = '\n'.join(row)
print(result)
```

Output

```
Input number of rows: 3
    1
   1 1
  1 2 1
 1 3 3 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This is much simpler:

```
ROWS = 5

def row( a, b ) :
   return ' ' * (b-a-1) + ' '.join([i for i in str(11**a)])

for i in range(ROWS) :
    print row( i, ROWS )
```

outputs:

```
    1
   1 1
  1 2 1
 1 3 3 1
1 4 6 4 1
```

and if you want this to work in python3, add parentheses in `print( .. )` call.